# How can I run a node.js file with a javascript command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to make an online game. It is not fast-paced, so I only need a json file. I am very new to node.js and don't really know much about it.

I have tried using this: https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/ and I understand how to read and write to it **with the command line**. How can I run a node js file from a javascript event like OnClick?

The node js:

```
//this code is mostly stolen from the site I linked to.
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

let newdata = {"newdata": "this is new!"}  
let data = JSON.stringify(newdata);  
fs.writeFileSync('data.json', data);
```

The json:

```
{
   "test": "hello world"
}
```

The html:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="
//run the node js file!!!
">
```

I have no idea what I can do to run the file.

Comment: nodeJS files are hosted in a web server, you can only access these using http methods, get, post..

Comment: You can't run a node.js file by clicking on a button.

Answer (score 1):

I think before you solve this problem you need to ask yourself what you tried to get.

1. If you want to make **a server** which sends in REST API the JSON file, the idea to using NodeJS is a good way, but you need to let the web server to run in the background and use `$.get` commands at the HTML code to get the data.
2. If you want to read the **JSON** file locally you didn't need to use NodeJS (JS will be the good way to solve this)

For the first solution:

**NodeJS code:**

```
const data = require('/path/to/json/file/data.json')
var path = require('path');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/data', (req, res) => {
    res.json(data)
})

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join('/path/to/index/file/index.html'));
});

app.listen('8080')
```

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            $.get("http://localhost:8080/data",
                function(data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            );
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I definitely need to make a server. What I want is to have a server online and type something like: server.player1.points and be able to read & write to it in real time. I currently have a domain, do I need to purchase anything else?

Comment: @Ben I add my solution to your problem